# Laravel always return UTC date

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

My Lumen Api Controller:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1444839127);
print_r($date);

$date2 = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1444839127, 'Europe/Stockholm')->setTimezone('Europe/Stockholm');
print_r($date2);

return [$date, $date2];
```

Output:

```
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2015-10-14 19:12:07.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Moscow
)
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2015-10-14 18:12:07.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Stockholm
)
["2015-10-14T16:12:07.000000Z","2015-10-14T16:12:07.000000Z"]
```

.env:

```
APP_TIMEZONE=Europe/Moscow
```

bootstrap/app.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'America/Sao_Paulo'));
```

Therefore, it seems that laravel print Carbon object correctly, but always returns a timestamp in the UTC format. Unfortunately i need it with timezone

Comment: inside `app.php`  change `'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',` then run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Unix timestamps are UTC, no way around it. If you need the equivalent time in another time zone, you have to convert.